# Is yii serve suitable for hosting in production?

Tags: php, yii2, webserver

I'm containerizing an existing PHP application that uses the Yii2 framework. For testing purposes I'm using `yii serve` from the command line to start a test server.

Is `yii serve` suitable for production deployments or is it similar to `django runserver` in that it's designed for getting developers up and running quickly but Apache or Nginx are expected to replace it in production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is, as you mentioned, similiar to `django runserver` and not really designed for production deployments. It could work, however there would be some drawbacks, for instance, only one request could be processed at a time, if there were multiple requests, the other ones should have to wait.

You should use Apache or Nginx with PHP to replace the developments' `yii serve` in production.